# How to get a list of output parameters from a Powershell Command

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a list of available output parameters for any PowerShell command.  In the example below I am able to pull all local user accounts then see all output parameters.  I would like to change this call to use **Get-Command** to get a list of each of the **output parameters** along with it's **data type**.  Once complete I can create a graphical program for users to select the output parameters they would like to monitor the value of.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-LocalUser | Select *


AccountExpires         : 
Description            : Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
Enabled                : False
FullName               : 
PasswordChangeableDate : 
PasswordExpires        : 
UserMayChangePassword  : True
PasswordRequired       : False
PasswordLastSet        : 10/5/2017 5:37:56 PM
LastLogon              : 5/18/2018 5:14:41 PM
Name                   : Administrator
SID                    : S-1-5-21-3668809925-1639166356-1269516417-500
PrincipalSource        : Local
ObjectClass            : User
```

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on whether the author of the command actually declares the expected output type - which is completely optional!

`Get-Command` already reports the declared output type(s) for a given command:

```
PS ~> $command = Get-Command Get-Service
PS ~> $command.OutputType.Type

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ServiceController                        System.ComponentModel.Component
```

Here we can see that `Get-Service` declares 1 output type, the `ServiceController` class.

We could take it a step further and use a bit of reflection to discover all properties and fields pertaining to said type:

```
function Show-ExpectedOutputTypeMember {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$CommandName
  )

  # resolve command name
  foreach($command in Get-Command $CommandName) {
    $foundAny = $false
    # test every declared output type for each resolved command
    $command.OutputType |ForEach-Object {
      # skip if the type declaration cannot be resolved
      if (-not $_.Type) {return}

      $foundAny = $true

      # enumerate all properties along with their type
      $_.Type.GetProperties() |Select-Object Name,ReflectedType,@{Name='Type';Expression='PropertyType'},@{Name='Command';Expression={$command}}
      # enumerate all fields along with their type
      $_.Type.GetFields() |Select-Object Name,ReflectedType,@{Name='Type';Expression='FieldType'},@{Name='Command';Expression={$command}}
    } |Format-Table Name,Type -GroupBy @{
        Name='OutputType'
        Expression = {
          $cmdName = $_.Command.Name 
          $outputTypeName = [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTypeNameToPSTypeName($_.ReflectedType)
          return "${cmdName} returns ${outputTypeName}"
        }
    }

    if (-not $foundAny) {
      Write-Warning "Unable to find any resolvable output types for '$($command.Name)'"
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can easily discover and resolve the declared output types and show **their public .NET members** (*):

```
PS ~> Show-ExpectedOutputTypeMember Get-Service


   OutputType: Get-Service returns [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]

Name                Type
----                ----
CanPauseAndContinue System.Boolean
CanShutdown         System.Boolean
CanStop             System.Boolean
DisplayName         System.String
DependentServices   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[]
MachineName         System.String
ServiceName         System.String
ServicesDependedOn  System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[]
ServiceHandle       System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle
Status              System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus
ServiceType         System.ServiceProcess.ServiceType
StartType           System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode
Site                System.ComponentModel.ISite
Container           System.ComponentModel.IContainer

PS ~> Show-ExpectedOutputTypeMember Get-Content


   OutputType: Get-Content returns [byte]

Name     Type
----     ----
MaxValue System.Byte
MinValue System.Byte


   OutputType: Get-Content returns [string]

Name   Type
----   ----
Length System.Int32
Chars  System.Char
Empty  System.String
```

***Unfortunately***, the cmdlets from the `LocalAccounts` module *don't declare output types*:

```
PS ~> Show-ExpectedOutputTypeMember Get-LocalGroup
WARNING: Unable to find any resolvable output types for 'Get-LocalGroup'
PS ~> Show-ExpectedOutputTypeMember Get-LocalUser
WARNING: Unable to find any resolvable output types for 'Get-LocalUser'
```

So the sad answer is: **yes, for some commands** - just not the ones you're interested in :)

*) Synthetic ETS instance properties will *not* be listed. As an example, `Get-Content` adds a `ReadCount` NoteProperty to each line read from a file - but since it's not part of the underlying `FileInfo` type it won't be discoverable via normal .NET reflection

Comment: Mathias, thank you for the detailed response.  Unfortunately, you are correct that my primary use case at the moment is within the LocalAccounts module so I can't use the parsing algo you created.  One way I considered is to process the entire function then parse the first instance of results then while parsing attempt to determine the datatype based on parsing results.  I've done that for W3C files.

Comment: @Mike That's a solved problem, you can simply do `Get-LocalAccounts |Get-Member` (or `Get-LocalAccounts |Select-Object -First 1 |Get-Member` if you _really_ want to interrupt `Get-LocalAccounts` as soon as possible)